# NoClassDefFoundError thrown during spark-submit

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, package

I'm trying to do a spark-submit as follows:

```
spark-submit --class com.subex.roc.apche.spark.IgniteSample 
--master localhost --deploy-mode client spark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

The following is the project structure :

[image]

The POM file to the project

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.subex.roc</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>spark</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
            <artifactId>ignite-spark_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0.final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run the spark-submit, it throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ignite/spark/JavaIgniteContext
    at com.subex.roc.apche.spark.IgniteSample.main(IgniteSample.java:55)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ignite.spark.JavaIgniteContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

`JavaIgniteContext` is a class available in `ignite-spark_2.10` jar which is already added as a maven dependency.Yet it seems spark is not able to find it in the class path. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JAR` does not include your dependencies after it has been packaged.

Add this code to your `pom.xml` under the `plugins` section:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

And add the file `assembly.xml` to your resources directory:

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.3 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.3.xsd">
    <!-- TODO: a jarjar format would be better -->
    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
    <formats>
        <format>jar</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
            <useProjectArtifact>true</useProjectArtifact>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

And then you can run `mvn clean clean install` or `mvn package`.

**NOTE: You then need to use the jar-with-dependencies file as your runnable jar.**